# Is there a website that can list the English cognates of German words?

Tags: learning

I think learning the cognates of German words would really help learning German as I know through reading, 'deer' is a cognate of 'Tier', which I wouldn't have guessed otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a list (probably not complete) at the Wiktionary Appendix:

[**Appendix:List of German cognates with English**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English)

Your example is listed at section

1.3.3 [Proto-Germanic *d (dt <-> d, t <-> d, tt <-> d, tt <-> dd)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:List_of_German_cognates_with_English#Proto-Germanic_*d_(dt_%3C-%3E_d,_t_%3C-%3E_d,_tt_%3C-%3E_d,_tt_%3C-%3E_dd))

[image]
**...**
[image]

---

> I think learning the cognates of German words would really help learning German

I am not a 100% sure if knowing more about the cognates really helps in learning the language, because it can lead to misunderstandings, and usage of notorious *"false friends"* in each other language.
I am trying to give you an example (and you can probably find many more from the list mentioned above):

**Kraft** (germ. for *force, power*) is a cognate with **craft** (in germ. *Handwerk, Handwerkskunst* ), which have completely different meanings in both languages.

I'd say knowing cognates starts to get interesting if you already know both languages at a mature and stable state. But for learning one of the distantly related languages not so much.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfgang Pfeifer's excellent German etymological dictionary is incorporated in this site:

https://www.dwds.de/

If there are English cognates they will be mentioned.